# Split affixes to prefix, root and suffix using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a text file called for_split.txt file that has the following content on it:

```
malam
ba-calle
pem-porut#an
daun #kulu
arau/araw
imbaw//nimbaw
dengo | nengo
dodop=am
{di} dalam
di {dalam}
+meri [b]
```

I use the following script to to split them:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('final_result.txt', 'w')

import re
with open('a.txt') as f:
new_split = [item.strip() for item in f.readlines()]

for word in new_split:
m = re.match(r"(?:\{[^-#={}/|]+\})?(?:([^-#={}/|]+)-)?([^-#={}/|]+)(?:/[^-#={}/|]+)?(?:[#=]([^-#={}/|]+))?", word)
if m:
    print("\t".join([str(item).lstrip() for item in m.groups()]))
else:
    print("(no match: %s)" % word)
```

the result looks like bellow:

```
None    malam   None
ba  calle   None
pem porut   an
None    daun    kulu
None    arau    None
None    imbaw   None
None    dengo   None
None    dodop   am
None    dalam   None
None    di  None
None    +meri [b]   None
```

that works pretty good for the others but It didn't work for the last words which is +meri [b] it should take the meri to root and the [b] to suffix instead of

```
None    +meri [b]   None
```

there should be

```
None +meri [b]
```

it should ignore the + from the beginning of meri and keep the meri to root and [b] to suffix is there any advice for this please? should I change my script to get the result can any one please help me with that thanks.

Comment: as for `UnicodeDecodeError` use this to open the file `with open('a.txt',encoding='utf-8') as f:` and the same for the file opened in `w` mode as well

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Comment: thanks so much @python_learner it works but I have one more question in python if it doesn't much any thing it give None is there any way to replace that to blank space?